# Replacement for cftree & cfmenu in coldfusion 2018

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2018

I knew, **cfgraph & cfgraphData** has been deprecated from  cf11 and we had a alternate solution as **cfchart,cfchartseries,cfchartdata**. Likewise what is the alternate solution for **cftree & cfmenu** ? I hope that's also deprecated in latest version.

Can someone point me to what is the replacements for these two tags ( cftree & cfmenu ) instead of using some other external js / libraries ?

Can we have any other solution for it without using other js / libraries ?

Comment: Both cftree and cfmenu do a lot of work. Bootstrap has similar functionality. In theory, you could build something. But you would end up reinventing Bootstrap or something similar.

Comment: @JamesAMohler so you mean there is no way to replacement for both in CFML ?

Comment: No, because they're client side code. They were already based on external javascript libraries.

Comment: So @Ageax we have to remove cftree & cfmenu from the code and should use some other external libraries like jstree etc.. ?

Comment: @Kannan.P - If they've removed (not just deprecated) those tags from CF2018, yes, because they won't work anymore.

Comment: Not sure, If they are deprecated mean then should provide the alternative solution for this kind scenario like cfgraph in to cfchart. Better adobe deprecate the entire UI related all tags. Because for each & every release they are removing UI related tags. So we can avoid UI related all and replace with some js framework in whole applications. That make sense too :) .

Comment: @Kannan.P It's been CF community's best practice to avoid all of the provided UI components in ColdFusion. Better to use a modern 3rd party UI framework that can be upgraded separately from the back-end processor.

Comment: Best bet is to eliminate your dependency on CF for this type of client side functionality. By that, I mean use a front end JavaScript lib to achieve the functionality that you need and never have to rely on Adobe to support that for you.

Comment: Not to mention, there are many 3rd party open sources libs that are very very well supported and have whole communities around them. If I was having trouble with Bootstrap-4, I am sure one of the 16k questions would help. And if I was still stuck, there would be a lot of people to answer questions.

Comment: @Kannan.P - I doubt they'll provide alternatives for most of those tags ... and that's probably a good thing ;-)  What convenience UI tags provide, is greatly outweighed by the lack of flexibility, and "upgradability". Since CF UI tags use external libraries anyway, you're better off cutting out the middle man.  Javascript isn't CF's bailiwick anyway.  Just use an external library directly. Then you're free to customize, upgrade (or not) however you see fit ;-)